# swrast_dri.so is still broken in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, mesa

I am trying to use an astronomy software package for my work, which apparently relies on some openGL libraries that are screwed up in Ubuntu 14.04.

This is the error I get (I get the same one when running the glxgears test script):

```
glxgears libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: driver does not expose __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast(): /usr/lib /x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast
```

I found this thread: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-lts-transitional/+question/259177

which seems to suggest that I should downgrade to libgl1-mesa-glx 10.0.1, but I have no idea how to do that cleanly (I started getting the packages and using dpkg to try to install them and ended up in dependency hell).

How can I get this to work? I really do not want to upgrade to 16.04 as it's highly likely all my other astronomy software will break.

Comment: Test in a virtual machine. VirtualBox is available for Linux.

Comment: Cross posted from https://askubuntu.com/questions/914884/swrast-dri-so-is-still-broken-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Please don't cross post